# How to split text at white-space while keeping the space?

Tags: javascript

```
'foo bar'.split(' ')
> ['foo', 'bar']
```

```
'foo   bar'.split(' ')
> ['foo', '', '', 'bar']
```

```
'foo   bar'.split(/\+s/)
> ['foo', 'bar']
```

Where as what I want is:

```
'foo   bar'.?
> ['foo', '   ', 'bar']
```

i.e. I want to split the text at a white space, but I want to capture the whitespace (however long) in the resulting array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a regular expression, and *capture* what you are splitting at, by putting it into round brackets:

```
'foo bar'.split(/( )/)
> ['foo', ' ', 'bar']
```

To capture any amount of any whitespace characters, use the `\s` class and the `+` quantifier:

```
'foo    bar'.split(/(\s+)/)
```

Comment: Edit: Should rather be `\s` than `\W` - the former is whitespace, the latter is "any character that is not a word character from the basic Latin alphabet."